# How to parser XML schema and fetch the property names

Tags: java, xml

I want to parse XML schema and then fetch elements from schema in that if there is complex object then that attributes should be fetch with prefix as main complex type.
 for instance

```
  <xs:element name="address" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="zipcode" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Address is complex type if we want to fetch zipcode then it should be like 'address.zipcode' 
Is there a way to do this or we have to check manually for type and create fields.

below is XML schema.

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="Employee">
 <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="empId" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="address" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="zipcode" type="xs:integer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: You want to parse... But with what? You did not state any technology...

Comment: I want to parse XML schema for fetching fields specified in schema so I am asking is there any way to parse schema from that we can get fields.and incase if it is complex object field then it should be prefixed by path

Comment: Again you write just "I want to parse", but how? The only tag is `xml`... Are you using XSLT, a coding language (which?), SQL (which RDBMS?), third party tools...

Comment: Sorry,in JAVA want to parse and fetch fields and I am not using XSLT,SQL

Comment: Actully, I want to fetch fields from schema then form a Mongo DB query according to that query I want to fetch data from Mongo DB

Comment: Java is not my thing, sorry... I'll edit the tag into your question. Please think of adding the correct tags immediately

Answer (score 0):

Extracting information from raw schema documents is challenging unless you know that the schema will be restricted to use a subset of the language: for example, that it will not use named model groups, or substitution groups, or complex types derived by extension.

It's easy to write something (e.g. in XSLT) that works with your examples  - or at least, it would be easy if we had a clearer picture of what output you wanted - but writing something that can handle ANY schema is much more difficult.

It may be better to work with the compiled representation of a schema produced by a "real" schema processor. For example Xerces has an API allowing access to the "schema components" produced by the schema compiler, and Saxon has an option to produce an SCM file (schema component model) which is an XML file containing the same information; at this level you don't have to cope with all the variety of ways the source schema might have been written.